# MapActivity does not take me to the exact location

Tags: android, maps

Friends i am making an application in which i am using Map Activity.

Now i have settles all Code using the following link:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

it gives ma an overlay on to the location as well. but when i zoom the map using

```
mapView.getController().setZoom(17);
```

Then it takes me to some other place not to the exact location where the overlay has been marked. So how do i take the map to that position?

Pleae Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the map location and fit and zoom to the location use

```
mapPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (21.232624 * 1E6), (int) (69.323265 * 1E6));
mc = mapView.getController();
mc.zoomToSpan((maxlat-minlat),(maxLng-minLng));
mc.animateTo(mapPoint);
```

and no need to specify the zoom level after this it's automatically zoom and span to that location

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the `animateTo(point)` to move the your current location to this particular GeoPoint . and point here is GeoPoint of your current location.